# SuiteCrm Install error

Tags: suitecrm

I´m installing suiteCrm version 7.10.2, license agree works fine, system check works fine but when i´m done with the database and sdmin config and hit next don´t appen anything. I check the console and get the ReferenceError: YAHOO is not defined
I´m installing in my domain and not locally.

In chrome console i get this error

install.php:14 GET https://www.digitalinput.pt/SuiteCRM-7.10.2/cache/include/javascript/sugar_grp1_yui.js?s=6.5.25&c= 404 (Not Found)

but the file exists and i add a 777 permission just to try and nothing changes!

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.htaccess` file. I can see you are using a subdirectory so make sure you have

`rewriteBase /SuiteCRM-7.10.2`

That should fix the 404.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give the 'cache' folder write access (Recursively)

if you have access to ssh, you can run this commmand on you terminal : 
Note : you need to be in the crm folder path

```
chmod 0777 -R cache/
```

then you refresh the page back